# How to use my TP-Link for internet and my ISP's router just for VoIP

Tags: router, isp, voip, wan, telephony

I've just upgraded from ADSL to VDSL, at the same ISP, and with that they sent me a new modem/router and they also switched my telephone line from POTS to VoIP.

I do not wish to use their modem/router for anything internet related, but just for the VOIP, which I am forced to if I want my telephone to work.

My router is a TP-Link Archer VR900, and what they've sent me is a SERCOMM H-300s.

What do I have to do to connect the two routers and have the TP-Link one handling the internet and the H-300s one handling just the VoIP?

What I've done so far is:

1. Use a splitter at the wall telephone outlet.
2. The "modem" port of the splitter goes to TP-Link's "DSL" port. The IP of that router is 192.168.1.1.
3. The "phone" port of the splitter goes to the H-300s's "Tel 1" (or "Tel 2") port. The IP of that router is 192.168.2.1. I have disabled wifi and DHCP.
4. An ethernet cable links a LAN port of TP-Link to a WAN port of the H-300s.
5. At another telephone outlet, I have plugged in a filter, and on top of that I've plugged my regular telephone device.

The telephone does not work, of course. I've also tried various other things at step 4 (e.g connecting LAN to LAN etc). I've also tried having H-300s at the same subnet as the TP-Link, at 192.168.1.2.

In case it matters, the ISPs VLAN IDs are: 835 for Internet, 836 for IPTV, 837 for VoIP.

Any ideas on what to try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to fully solve this, so I compromised with the following solution:

- Wall telephone outlet 1 ⟶ filter ⟶ telephone.
- Wall telephone outlet 2 ⟶ splitter.
- Splitter modem port ⟶ DSL port of H300s.
- Splitter phone port ⟶ Tel 1 port of H300s.
- H300s LAN (1, 2, or 3) port ⟶ TP-Link WAN port.

The H300s' IP is 192.168.2.1 and I've disabled IPv4 Firewall, Wifi, DHCP, UPnP, DNS, DDNS, DMZ, Parental Control.

The TP-Link's IP is 192.168.1.1 and I've:

- Changed its operation mode from "DSL Modem Router Mode" to "Wireless Router Mode".
- Enabled its "WAN Interface", set IP 192.168.2.2, subnet 255.255.255.0, gateway 192.168.2.1 (that's the H300s' IP), some DNS entries (e.g 94.140.14.14 and 94.140.15.15).
- Configure DHCP (with some DNS entries), Wifi, Firewall.
- All ethernet cabled and wifi devices go to the TP-Link.

The obvious drawback of this method is that internet is actually being provided by the crappy H300s, and also I now have an extra hop to reach anything on the internet (i.e my `tracert` goes to 192.168.1.1, then to 192.168.2.1, and then to my ISP.